# Error in an initialization statement

Tags: java, jsp

```
int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
```

It shows an error. Please help me to find out the error. I want to insert the "`age`" into the database

Comment: What error does it show? How are you submitting the request that contains the parameter `age`? Does it?

Comment: please explain your porblem properly..

Comment: "Please help me to find out the error" <-- without your even showing the relevant stacktrace?

Comment: Is it `NumberFormatException`? if yes, the parameter age seem to be NOT having a String containing integer only!

Comment: May be you are setting a value for age which is not an Integer from JSP.

Comment: I am just speechless at what a terrible question this is.  Please help me, but I'm not going to tell you what the problem is?  Come on, Abu, you can do much better than this.

Comment: @DavidWallace Encouraging Abu? Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

While submitting the request from web to servlet, the parameter age may be null, and please check your Ajax/form submission 
you can check like

```
int age = 0;
if(request.getParameter("age")!=null){
try{
age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
}catch(Exception e){
    //catch NumberFormatException if any
}
```

This would resolve you error.

Answer (score 0):

This will help to solve your problem

```
// provide check for age parameter not equal to null
int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age").toString());
```